# To define AreaID in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-query

I have **TFS 2010** with some areas set up before.
I need to get **AreaID** value.
How could I get **AreaID** for particular Area by Visual Studion UI without any coding?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you are not coding, what benefit is the AreaID to you?

Comment: I have script which has hardcoded AreaID. I need to change it to proper ID but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly as to why you may need to know AreaID... 
I'm in the situation where I want to set up a filter for a specific Area, but the filter is asking for AreaID (which I don't know).

IF you have access to the TFS Database you can run this...

```
SELECT      a.[Team Project],
            b.Title,
            a.ID,
            a.[Node name]
FROM    xxTree a
JOIN    WorkItemsAre b on a.ID = b.AreaID
WHERE a.[Node name] like '%foo%'
```

..which will actually bring back all work items associated with an area name like "foo"..

NB This works against TFS2012, unsure of 2010...
If you do not have access then maybe you could email the above to your admin if you have one...